# waitForSelector and querySelectorAll with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm a complete newbie with node.js and trying to do this automation.
I have this data to **scrape** with puppeteer and need just to catch the score number (85) and show in the console log.

```
<tr>
                                    <td class="text-right">
                                        Delivery Confidence Score <br>
                                        <span style="font-weight:normal;font-style:italic;font-size:12px">* the probability [0-100]% of an email making it into the mailbox of the recipient.</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-left bold-text">
                                        <span> 85<br><span class="green-text" style="font-weight:normal">Send mail. There is a high chance of email delivery success.</span> </span> &nbsp;&nbsp;

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
```

So after all open url, login and pass I have another search submit and need to catch the information above.
Following entire code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false}); // default is true
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const delay = require ("delay");
  await page.goto('https://www.melissa.com/user/signin.aspx?src=https://www.melissa.com/v2/lookups/emailcheck/email/');
  //authentication
  await page.waitFor('input[name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Signin1$txtEmail"]');
  await page.$eval('input[name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Signin1$txtEmail"]', elu => elu.value = '4n1kl4t0r@gmail.com');
  await page.waitFor('input[name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Signin1$txtPassword"]');
  await page.$eval('input[name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Signin1$txtPassword"]', elp => elp.value = 'v3r1fy>>2020');
  await page.click('input[type="submit"]');

  //search
  await page.waitFor('input[name="email"]');
  await page.$eval('input[name="email"]', el_e => el_e.value = '4n1kl4t0r@gmail.com');
  await page.click('input[type="submit"]');
  //await page.waitForNavigation();
  await delay(3000);
  //scraping score
  const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
  let score = document.querySelector('#tableInfo50 > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td.text-left.bold-text').innerText
  return {
  score
  }
  })

 console.log(result)

 browser.close()
})()
```

Hope you guys can help on something. Thanks

Comment: what is the exact problem which you are facing?

Comment: Hi @amitgupta. I'm getting this error. UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:8592) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code

Comment: I think the problem is because I have 1 page.goto then the first submit with the credentials then the search submit returning the information. Maybe puppeteer is trying to scrap in the first page, but I can't go directly to the second page without login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be that without loding of the second page it actually starts evaluating the first page. So after waitForNavigation use some delay.

For example :-

```
await delay(3000);
//scrapping score
const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
let score = document.querySelector('#tableInfo50 > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > 
td.text-left.bold-text').innerText
return {
score
}
})
```

use npm I delay to install the delay library.

Comment: Still getting the error. =[ Can I use another module to call after authentication?

Comment: does your screen which is having this table open up in new page?

Comment: Don't use the waitForNavigation and keep in mind to include the delay in this line in your code. const delay = require ("delay");

Comment: {
  score: '85\nSend mail. There is a high chance of email delivery success.   '
} this is the result which i get.

Comment: sorry @amit my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
await page.waitForNavigation(); 
score = await page.$eval('td.text-left span', el => el.innerText);
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks @iGuru1994 but didn't worked. 
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8592) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: I think the problem is because I have 1 page.goto then the first submit with the credentials then the search submit returning the information. Maybe puppeteer is trying to scrap in the first page, but I can't go directly to the second page without login.